# How to delete records that have same value in a column in Entity Framework?

Tags: entity-framework

I have a table in database that has some columns.I get a list of some records from this table in my repository class.So I will have something like this:

[image]

Now I want to delete records that have the same value in a special column(here in Code column),like this:

[image]

I mean I want to have just one of the records that have the same Code column value.
How can I do that in Entity Framework?

Comment: And which row should be kept? Doesn't matter? First? Max(name)?

Comment: No.It doesnt matter.I just want to remove records that have the same value in one special column(here Code column).

Comment: @HamidReza how many rows? 10's, 100's, 1,000's or more?

Comment: I want 5 rows of them.Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Let you are having two table `Table1` and `table2` and you want to delete all the records
from `table1` which are having same `code` number in table2.
**This is your requirement**

1.first you have to get all the values of code column of table2

1. `var x = db.table2.Select(p => p.code);`  Then you have to comapre it with table1 
   after that you have delete the records for those codes are same.
2. For that you have to write below piece of code.

   foreach (var item in x)
   {
   var y = db.table1.Where(p => p.code== item).FirstOrDefault();
   if (y != null)
   {
   db.table1.DeleteObject(y);
   db.SaveChanges();
   }
   else
   {
   }
   }

Answer (score 0):

Group by the `Code` column, skip the first record of each group and delete the rest:

```
var query = db.Records.GroupBy(r => r.Code)
              .Select(grouping => grouping.OrderBy(ent => ent.EntityId).Skip(1));

foreach (var element in query.SelectMany (q => q))
{
    db.Records.Remove(element);
}

db.SaveChanges();
```